# Return to previous page after continuous unsuccessful form submissions in Play framework

Tags: forms, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I want to get the URL of the previous page in my PlayFramework Java controller. I know that it is possible to get it with:

```
String refererUrl = request().getHeader("referer");
```

But Imagine a page that contains a FORM with a SAVE and a CANCEL button. If the user presses the save button, the form will be controlled in the controller and if some errors exist, then it goes to the same page and asks the user to correct the form.

now imagine that the user did not enter the data correctly, so he gets back to the form to correct it. now the user again does not correct the form and presses SAVE for the second time. so it will be redirected again to the form. Now if the user presses cancel, it will go to the last page, which is the form with errors, and this is not what I want.

One way is tho give the previous URL as a parameter to the page. but I dont really like having long URLs, so is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Ajax requests for form submitting and do your redirecting in JavaScript. This way you can decide based on your request, whether it is ok or has errors, to redirect or just update the page with the form validation errors.

Your form could look something like this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/">

  <!-- My input -->

  <button type="button">Cancel</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "mySubmitURL",
    data: $('#myForm').serialize(), 
    success: function(response) {
        // Redirect to the new page
    },
    error: function(response) {
        // Show your errors that you submitted in the response
    }
  });
});
```

Now you need an controller that handles the POST request and returns the form errors as JSON in case there are some:

```
public Result mySubmitURL() {
    Form<MyModel> form = Form.form(MyModel.class)
            .bindFromRequest();
    if (form.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(form.errorsAsJson());
    }
    // Do something with your form data, e.g. store it
    return ok();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the referer into the template:

**Controller action:**

```
public Result something() {
   String refererUrl = request().getHeader("referer");
   return ok(views.html.something.render(refererUrl));
}
```

then you could create a condition for the 'cancel' button.

**template:**

```
@(referer: String)

@if(referer.equals("THE_URL_YOU_DONT_WANT_TO_REDIRECT") {
   <a href="the page you would like him to redirect"> cancel </a>
} else {
   <a href="@referer"> cancel </a>
}
```